# How to get down the streets in Chapter 4?

Tags: steam, max-payne-3

In Chapter 4, just after killing four guys in some wrecked building, Passos yells from a balcony that "there is a way down the street."  But the guy isn't moving and he's blocking the way out.  The only way I found to get outside it was by jumping on his left side. But after a short while, while going down the rusty stairs, I die without any reason, just like if some game script couldn't trigger properly...

Is this a bug or glitch?  Am I missing something?

[image: Passos blocking the way]

Comment: In the case where this is a bug, the Steam tag is actually revelant; don't remove it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so yeah, it was a bug.  According to [this video](http://youtu.be/p8DURYXIToM?t=3m17s), there's nothing special to do; just come closer from Passos, and a cutscene (what else ?) will start, unveiling the rest of the level.

In order to get over this bug, I had to leave the game and reload my last save; from there, everything went fine.